# Prevent text from clipping in a div containing various child elements, without resizing text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have some `divs` that need to fit a variety of text elements within them. There are multiple elements (`p`, `h1`, `li`, `pre`)

Every solution I've seen only works for single elements in a `div`, or works by resizing the content to fit.

Is there a way to just clip lines that do not fully fit?

I'm using ReactJS and am open to Javascript or CSS solutions.

**Example of issue**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using JQuery. The basic idea is that, on page load, the column-width css attribute of each of your containing divs (the ones holding the text) will be set to the inner width of that div. This should prevent your text from being trimmed at the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($(".box"), function(i, box){
        $(box).css("column-width", $(box).innerWidth() + "px")
    });
});
```

In normal Javascript -

```
window.onload = function(){
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
    boxes[i].style.columnWidth = boxes[i].style.width + "px"
  }
}
```